# how can i install php-json for php 4.3.3?

Tags: php, json

i think the title is self-explanatory, i work with easyPHP 1.7, which has the php version 4.3.3, which by itself doesn't include support for json, so i found php-json on the web but don't know how to set it up. so can someone help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know easyPHP but I'd suggest you upgrade to something that comes with a more recent PHP-distribution.

On the other hand: before json-support was included in PHP 5.2 I used the PEAR-package [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=services+json). You can install this via PEAR, or just include the one JSON.php file that you can download. Good news is, is that it supports PHP 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON module for PHP 4.3 can be found in [PECL](http://pecl.php.net). Unfortunately for you, the packages are provided in a form of a source code, so you have to compile them manually and this is a quite serious problem on Windows. There is another service, pecl4win with binary DLL-s, but it seems to be down now.

I'd suggest you to update PHP to some newer version, because PHP4 is neither supported nor developed and the same is with PHP-JSON for PHP 4.3. Note that the module is going to be a part of PHP core since 5.3.0 version.

Comment: pecl4win has been down for a while now. In any case, php 4 is ancient, so upgrading to a current version would be the sane choice.