# php4 with json data

Tags: php4

Can someone help me to setup php4 for using json?

Thanks!

Comment: See [
how can i install php-json for php 4.3.3 ?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961446/how-can-i-install-php-json-for-php-4-3-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself but you can have a look over here...

[How to use JSON in PHP 4 or PHP 5.1.x](http://www.epigroove.com/posts/97/how_to_use_json_in_php_4_or_php_51x)

Googling up the "json in php4" should give some handy results.

Comment: funny how that works. that google query let me here.

Answer (score 0):

This also looks like it may be a viable option http://willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/