# Parse and Stringify JSON in PHP 4

Tags: php, json, php4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php4 with json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481927/php4-with-json-data)

Is there a library or class that provides parsing (JSON to PHP primitives/arrays) and stringifying (PHP primitives/arrays to JSON) for PHP 4?

Comment: See [
php4 with json data
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481927/php4-with-json-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also looks like it may be a viable option
http://willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/