# Content type for PHP serialized data

Tags: php, serialization, mime-types

I am trying to find the correct (or best) content type to pass to header() when outputting serialized PHP data.  The best I could find when searching was [a proposal](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-types/current/msg00161.html) for application/vnd.php.serialized and [another person asking the same question](https://www.mail-archive.com/code4lib@listserv.nd.edu/msg04446.html) without a definitive answer.  I was considering using just text/plain and moving on.
The data being serialized is an associative array, 1-3 levels nested. Values are always string/int/bool, in order of occurrence.

For reasoned I'd rather not get into, my application is using PHP4.  Otherwise I would be using JSON and be on my way.

**Edit:** My question is not about how to work with JSON in PHP.
For those interested: I am handling JSON encode/decode using the 'Services_JSON' PEAR package , however I've noticed performance issues which PHP serialized resolves.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer. As long as `text/plain` works for you then keep using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php4 with json data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481927/php4-with-json-data)

Comment: @Technoh - I'm inclined to agree and it is - wanted to see what other SO folks thought.

Comment: Thats a good question, I am looking for an answer to this since a very long time. To know what file-extension fits best is interresting too

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a real official answer, but the best matching answer I can find is:

```
application/php-serialized
```

or better

```
application/php-serialized; charset=UTF-8
```